What is the functionality of vault-agent-status annotation?
I have gone through documentation of hashicorp vault agent annotations and am not able to clearly understand the significance of vault-agent-status annotation?
Does it mean that if the value "injected" is provided to this annotation, then the apis to fetch password and will only be invoked on password change not on the events like token renewal?

As per this A Hands-On Guide to Vault in Kubernetes blog written by Anvesh Muppeda :


vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: “true”: Enables Vault Agent    injection for this pod.

vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status: “update”: Ensures the status    of secret injection is updated.



The vault-agent-status annotation in HashiCorp Vault's Kubernetes tells us how the Vault Agent interacts with your application pods.When you set  value  to "injected", it says that the Vault Agent has successfully injected the secrets into the pod and yes,the APIs to fetch password and will only be invoked on password change not on the events like token renewal.
This status helps the application to understand that it can now safely access the secrets that have been injected.
Refer to this blog written by Dominik Engelhardt, for more information and also go through this document written by Bibin Wilson,which might be helpful.

Thanks. Is it possible for you to please explain "agent.auth.handler: lifetime watcher done channel triggered" as well?
I am getting this occasionally in my logs after which the agent-inject-command and agent-inject-template gets invoked. Any idea on this one?

Once go through this Annotations document which might be helpful for you.
